# Laravel DB query of temporary table with subquery, join and group by

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables. Companies and Supplierverifs;

Companies: id, uuid, name.

Supplierverifs is supplier_id, manufacturer_id, test_date.

Both supplier_id and manufacturer_id are foreign keys linking to the companies table.

I need to get a list of each unique set of supplier_id and manufacturer_id.

For example:

1, NULL

1, 2

1, 1

2, NULL

Here is my working query. Trying to figure out how to write this with \DB class.

```sql
select supplier_id, 
       manufacturer_id, 
       s.uuid supplier_uuid, 
       m.uuid manufacturer_uuid, 
       s.name supplier_name, 
       m.name manufacturer_name 
             
       from (    select supplier_id, 
                 manufacturer_id 
                 from supplierverifs 
                 where account_id = ?   ) us
             
       left join companies s
       on s.id = supplier_id
       left join companies m
       on m.id = manufacturer_id
       GROUP BY supplier_id, manufacturer_id
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
$verifs = \DB::table(\DB::raw("(select supplier_id, manufacturer_id from supplierverifs where account_id = $id) us"))
        ->select(\DB::raw("supplier_id, manufacturer_id, s.uuid supplier_uuid, m.uuid manufacturer_uuid, s.name supplier_name, m.name manufacturer_name"))
        ->leftJoin(\DB::raw('companies s'),'s.id','=','supplier_id')
        ->leftJoin(\DB::raw('companies m'), 'm.id','=','manufacturer_id')
        ->groupBy("supplier_id","manufacturer_id")
        ->get();
```

But I cannot do anything with the results, and dd prints nothing.

Comment: You can use `DB::raw` or `DB::statement` and for my opinion if you always query that thing better to use a statement query to create a view table on database using migration and then you can use reqular DB::select on that view table.

Comment: Very interestingly, I tried this approach -- I was shocked to see that MYSQL queries on a view in my application took 600 ms to complete. With Laravel eager loading, although it was broken up into 12 queries, it took 40 ms to complete all of them. I have tested many views and they are always much much slower than multiple slim queries.